# What does zip do, in layman's terms?

Tags: swift, zip

I stumbled into 'zip' in some code I'm studying.

So I looked it up to get the following:

`zip(_:_:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip

[image: zip screenshot]

This is about as clear as milk.

What does zip do and when would you use it?

Comment: it combines two sequences. similar to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: The phrase "where the elements of the ith pair are the ith elements of each underlying sequence" is _perfectly_ clear and expresses it completely accurately.

Answer (score 7):

Zip takes a pair of sequences, and turns them into a sequence of pairs.

So the two sequences:

```
A = 1, 2, 3
B = 4, 5, 6
```

Zipped become:

```
zip(A, B) = (1,4), (2,5), (3,6)
```

Comment: What is a 'sequence'? ...says the ignorant.

Comment: I don't know swift, but in every other language that uses the term, it's an ordered collection of values. Not necessarily a "list" or "array" which may refer to more concrete types.

Comment: Specifically, `zip` takes parameters that conform to the `SequenceType` protocol. As per Apple doco, SequenceType is "A type that can be iterated with a `for...in` loop". There are a lot of classes that implement SequenceType, including Array.

Comment: And there are also a lot of sequence types that aren't arrays. The great thing about protocol methods like `zip` is that they work the same whether you have an array, a range, a string's `characters` view, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two arrays, one of `[Int]` and one of `[String]`:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Then passing these two arrays to `zip` will get you an array of pairs containing these elements in the same order:

```
let c = zip(a, b) // => [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the given answers, I thought this would be helpful to add as an answer instead of a comment:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let c = Array(zip(a, b)) // [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

This is useful if you want to compare the two arrays with each other when you don't know the exact sizes of the arrays and the **length** is not an issue:

```
let d = zip(a, b).map { $0.0 + $0.1 } // [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Don't compare `Sequence`s with `zip(_:_:)`. **Especially** when you don't know the lengths of them. You'll get a false positive!

Comment: @DennisVennink Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it please? Perhaps with an example so I can see what I did wrong.

Comment: `zip(_:_:)` truncates the longer `Sequence`. So, if you compare two `Sequence`s, you'll get a false positive, e.g., `zip([0, 1], [0, 1, 2]).allSatisfy({$0.0 == $0.1}) == true`, which is wrong; it should be `false`.

Comment: @DennisVennink Thanks, that's quite clear. I don't agree with you though because if the length is an issue, you're obviously not gonna use `zip(_:_:)`. The example you used is right, it's just your test case is wrong if you want to compare sequences.